# Poincarè inequality in probability

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm looking for a proof of the poincarré inequality in a probabilitic setting. That is to say, let $\mu$ be a probability on $\Bbb R^n$, what are the hypothesis in order to have, for any f smooth

$\int_{R^n}|f|^p d\mu -(\int f d\mu)^p \leq \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\nabla f|^p d\mu $

I know there is a proof in the case $p=2$ but the only hypothesis i found where about a gaussian measure. are there more genereal hypothesis?
In any case could you give me a reference also for the proof of the $p=2$ +gaussian case?
Thank you very much